# How to execute 2 SQLlite Queries with single command

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to execute 2 sql queries here. for this purpose i have using 2 sqlcommands here.but I think that it is not the right way. Code duplication is the main prbl.so how to Handel this. Or this is the right way?

```
string UserStatus = "update Users SET Status=0";
SQLiteCommand setStatusCmd = new SQLiteCommand(StatusQuery);
setStatusCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
setStatusCmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
setStatusCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string UpdateQuery = ("UPDATE Users SET password ='" + password + "', + "' WHERE name = '" + userName + "'; ");
SQLiteCommand updateCmd = new SQLiteCommand(userUpdateQuery);
updateCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
updateCmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The first update is modifying the status of _all_ users, while the second query targets just a single user.  These queries belong as separate things.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so this is right?

Comment: It's right in being two separate things. @TimBiegeleisen is absolutely correct - you're doing two separate and distinct things, and they should remain separate and distinct.

Comment: Also, you should not be concatenating user input into your SQL statement. Google "Little Bobby Tables" and then "parameterized queries".